# MySQL - mysql_fetch_assoc() doesn't give one column

Tags: php, mysql

My column type is `SMALLINT` and name is `user_level`.
Here is the code I am using:

```php
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*********");
mysql_select_db("3591_other");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rivase_f_users WHERE user_name = '$email' AND    user_pass=sha1('$passwd')");
if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
//snip
else if (mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['username']=$email;
    if ($row['user_level']==1) {$_SESSION['usertype']='leader';}
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

`$row['user_level']` looks like to be `null`, but phpmyadmin says it is `1`. I tried echoing it with commenting the header-location row, it did not say anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Again someone who use `mysql_*` functions. Btw `WHERE user_name = '$email'` Did you read this????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
else if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION['username']=$email;
    if ($row['user_level']==1) {$_SESSION['usertype']='leader';}
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to accomplish is unclear to me but you are discarding the first result:

```
else if (mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Read and discard
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Read next row
```

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a logical `if-else` bug.

You are reading the value of next `mysql_fetch_assoc()` after testing the output result of the first call in the `else` condition, but you wanted to read the value from first returned result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code try this

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*********");
mysql_select_db("3591_other");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rivase_f_users WHERE user_name = '$email' AND    user_pass=sha1('$passwd')");
if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
//snip
else if ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION['username']=$email;
    if ($row['user_level']==1) {$_SESSION['usertype']='leader';}
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

I've changed the else if check to save the row when doing the comparison.